# Can I access an external WebServices in Azure Websites (WAWS)

Tags: web-services, azure, asp-classic, azure-web-app-service

I have a classic ASP website hosted at Azure using Websites.

Now I need this site to access a set of WebServices located externally... I wrote a quick/dirty ASP page to check and it always times out... It seems as it was blocked.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?  Please find below my quick test code.

```
Dim objRequest, objXMLDoc, objXmlNode
Dim strRet, strError, strNome
Dim strName

strName= "?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=BRL"

Set objRequest = Server.createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

With objRequest
    .open "GET", "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx" & strName, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    .setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"
    .send
End With

Set objXMLDoc = Server.createobject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
objXmlDoc.async = false

Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.Write(objRequest.ResponseText)
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error text you're seeing?

Comment: do you know where exactly it times out? You absolutely can do requests to other http resources from Azure Web-sites. I do it in my projects.